# Is there any sane way to watch for a condition when debugging Perl code?

Tags: perl, debugging

I tried using the `w` command of `perl -d`, giving it a condition like `w ($root =~ /something/)` to stop when `$root` changes, but it has this habit of stopping even if the variable just goes out of scope. So it's useless to me. I tried adding something like `w (!$root || $root =~ /something/)` but that seems to lead to some weird behaviour like stopping randomly and going into random `sub`s. And in any case, even if this latter one worked it'll stop if the new scope contains a variable with the same name, so I'd prefer not to have to use it.

So, is there any other way of achieving a current-scope-only watch with the Perl debugger? Or is there any other console debugger for Perl that provides this?

Comment: Can you narrow it down to a statement? If so, use the conditional breakpoint instead.

Comment: No, that's the problem, I don't know where the change occurs and would like to use watch to find that.

Comment: Devel::ebug is a newish perl debugger. I don't know how well it would compare with the vanilla perl debugger since I have not used it or the bundled debugger very thoroughly (my needs are quite modest). The ebug application that ships with Devel::ebug is designed to be extended and customized. Perhaps it could serve your needs. In any case it's project worth watching (so to speak).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe there is anything built into the debugger that will do this but I rolled my own tied scalar class and set a breakpoint on the "ScalarSnoop::STORE" subroutine.

Here's the class:

```
package ScalarSnoop;

use strict;
use base qw(Tie::Scalar);

sub TIESCALAR {
  my $class = shift;
  my $value = shift;
  return bless \$value, $class;
}

sub FETCH {
  my $self = shift;
  return $$self;
}

sub STORE {
  my $self = shift;
  my $newvalue = shift;
  $$self = $newvalue;
}
1;
```

And here is a script that uses it:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use v5.14.0;
use strict;
use warnings;

use lib qw(.);
use ScalarSnoop;

my ($first, $second, $third);
tie $second, 'ScalarSnoop';

$first  = 'hey';
$second = 'there';
$third  = 'dude';

# Changing the iterator variable changes the original since
# it is an alias
foreach my $variable (($first, $second, $third)) {
  $variable = "like, ${variable}";
  say "$variable";
}
```

Start up the debugger and set a breakpoint with `b postpone ScalarSnoop::STORE`. Continue running and the debugger will stop when someone stores a value in your scalar. Then you can dump the stack trace and see who it was.

Comment: I want the execution to stop only when the new value is different from the old value, not every time an assignment takes place. Is it possible with perhaps a "b postpone ScalarSnoop::_NEW_STORE" where _NEW_STORE is a sub that STORE calls when it finds $self and $newvalue are unequal?

Comment: Absolutely. The `b postpone` syntax can accept an additional condition so that it only gets triggered if the condition expression is true. Something like `b postpone ScalarSnoop::STORE $_[1] ne 'original value'` should work.